# Snowflake procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, procedure

Basically I have created the notification alert using integrating AWS and Snowflake.
I want to add variable to my select statement. But its not working. So it will be for example "The token of user has expierd (name of the user).

Here is my function

```
`create or replace external function helloemailworld
(Sender varchar,Receiver Varchar , SUBJECT varchar, BODY_TEXT varchar)
 returns variant
 api_integration = hellotesting
 as 'https://....execute-api.eu-...l-1.amazonaws.com/dev/helloworld';`
```

and here is my procedure

```
create or replace procedure Notification()
  returns variant
  language javascript
  EXECUTE AS caller
  as     
  $$  
    var my_sql_command = "select * from notification";
    var statement1 = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: my_sql_command} );
    var result_set1 = statement1.execute();
    
  
       
    while (result_set1.next())  {
       var column1 = result_set1.getColumnValue(1);
       var column2 = result_set1.getColumnValue(2);
       var column3 = result_set1.getColumnValue(3);
       
       
     
 var execute = "select helloemailworld('lukasz@gmail.com','lukasz@op.pl','Alert', 'The token of user has expierd' + column1);"
 
 var statement2= snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: execute} );
 var result_set2 = statement2.execute();
      
       }
  $$
  ;
```

The column 1 is a variable and in notification table first column is also a variable

Comment: Can you add details to explain "but its not working"?

Comment: If I'm executing the procedure I'm receving email from aws "We have received a request to authorize this email address for use with Amazon SES and Amazon Pinpoint in region Europe (Frankfurt). If you requested this verification, please go to the following URL to confirm that you are authorized to use this email address:We have received a request to authorize this email address for use with Amazon SES and Amazon Pinpoint in region Europe (Frankfurt). If you requested this verification, please go to the following URL to confirm that you are authorized to use this email address" every time

Comment: I have veryficated email in my AWS